# php paths differ between ajax use and php use

Tags: php, jquery, path

I just stumbled upon a (at least for me) new weird behavior of paths while using php functions with pure php or ajax calls.

If I use just php the path in the php function is like:

```
require_once('wp-content/themes/xxx/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

but if I use the exact same function with an ajax call, the path needs to be like this to make it work:

```
require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Can you explain me why this is so? Thank you very much!

Comment: `Can you explain me why this so?` No! Not without knowing a lot more about your code

Comment: Is the file which contains the "require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');"  being 'included' by different files depending on the call type? And if so, are these parent files in different directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting that behavior is because all the includes are occuring from the root of the wordpress install so you are saying do down the directory structure several layers before you get to the file. Breaking it down it does like this.

```
wp-content/  Go down one directory level from the file i'm in
themes/      Then go down into the themes directory
xxx/         Then go to the xxx directory
tcpdf/       Then go to the tcpdf directory
tcpdf.php  This is the file you want
```

When you are doing the second include you are in a directory that shares a parent with `wp-content/themes/xxx/tcpdf/` so what you are saying is

```
../        Go up one directory level
tcpdf/     Go into the tcpdf directory
tcpdf.php  This is the file you want
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess when you are using it without an AJAX call, you are including it from some other file, that can make the difference.
However I recommend storing the application root directory in a constant (e.g. ROOT) and then you include everything relative to ROOT.

Comment: That's how I've always done it. This way the file is always included from the same directory no matter where you go.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the include path to `set_include_path ( APP_ROOT )`. By doing so, ALL includes/requires will be relative to the application root that you will define in the constant `APP_ROOT`.

PHP normally has the current directory as include path, which can lead to problems like this you're having.